# Azure AD B2C - Authentication Challenge not triggering authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am playing around with Azure AD B2C and I have a weird behavior. I created a new app following this sample: [AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/tree/complete/WebApp-B2C-DotNet)  and it works like a charm.

Then I ported the code to an existing app and I get a problem. In a Controller, I have the following method:

```
[PolicyAuthorize(Policy = "b2c_1_signin01")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new IndexModel
    {
        FundsDocumentsModel = new FundsDocumentsModel { DocumentTypes = this.DocumentTypes_ReadDictionary() }
    };

    if (this.FundId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        var data = new FinanceDataProvider();
        var fund = data.GetFundById(this.FundId);

        if (fund != null)
        {
            this.ViewBag.LocalSubTitle = "for " + fund.Name;
        }
    }

    return this.View("~/Areas/DataRoom/Views/Index.cshtml", vm);
}
```

The code of the PolicyAuthorize attribute is the same as in the sample mentionned above:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class PolicyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Policy { get; set; }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties(
                    new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { Constants.POLICY_KEY, this.Policy }
                    })
                {
                    RedirectUri = "/",
                }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

When I access my web app in debug, I am automatically taken to the Index method of the controller. Then I go in the HandleUnauthorizedRequest of the attribute and the Challenge method is called.

But I am not redirected to the B2C login page. Instead, the debugger comes back to the Index method like if I was authenticated, which I do not want.

Now, if I go to /Account/SignIn (which have the same implementation as in the sample app), I get redirected to the B2C login page.

The problem is that in the sample app, whenever I use the PolicyAuthorize attribute, I get redirected to the B2C login page.

So I do not understand where this difference can come from. Do you guys have any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Here is more code, to show everything has been ported.

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.CLIENT_ID,
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.REDIRECT_URI,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.REDIRECT_URI,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = this.AuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // The PolicyConfigurationManager takes care of getting the correct Azure AD authentication
            // endpoints from the OpenID Connect metadata endpoint.  It is included in the PolicyAuthHelpers folder.
            ConfigurationManager = new PolicyConfigurationManager(
                string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.AAD_INSTANCE, ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.TENANT, "/v2.0", Constants.OIDC_METADATA_SUFFIX),
                new[] { ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.SIGNUP_POLICY_ID, ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.SIGNIN_POLICY_ID, ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.PROFILE_POLICY_ID }),

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
            },
        };

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This notification can be used to manipulate the OIDC request before it is sent. Here we use it to send the correct policy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">The notification.</param>
    private async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        PolicyConfigurationManager mgr = notification.Options.ConfigurationManager as PolicyConfigurationManager;
        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None, notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke.Properties.Dictionary[Constants.POLICY_KEY]);
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.EndSessionEndpoint;
        }
        else
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None, notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary[Constants.POLICY_KEY]);
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.AuthorizationEndpoint;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notification">The notification.</param>
    private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();
        notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

HttpDocumentRetriever.cs:

```
public class HttpDocumentRetriever : IDocumentRetriever
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpDocumentRetriever()
        : this(new HttpClient())
    { }

    public HttpDocumentRetriever(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        Guard.AgainstNullArgument(nameof(httpClient), httpClient);

        this._httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        Guard.AgainstNullArgument(nameof(address), address);

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await this._httpClient.GetAsync(address, cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new IOException("Unable to get document from: " + address, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

PolicyConfigurationManager.cs:

```
// This class is a temporary workaround for AAD B2C,
// while our current libraries are unable to support B2C
// out of the box.  For the original source code (with comments)
// visit https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs
public class PolicyConfigurationManager : IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>
{
    public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultAutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0, 0);

    public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30);

    public static readonly TimeSpan MinimumAutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);

    public static readonly TimeSpan MinimumRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);

    private const string policyParameter = "p";

    private TimeSpan _automaticRefreshInterval = DefaultAutomaticRefreshInterval;
    private TimeSpan _refreshInterval = DefaultRefreshInterval;
    private Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> _syncAfter;
    private Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> _lastRefresh;

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _refreshLock;
    private readonly string _metadataAddress;
    private readonly IDocumentRetriever _docRetriever;
    private readonly OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever _configRetriever;
    private Dictionary<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration> _currentConfiguration;

    public PolicyConfigurationManager(string metadataAddress, string[] policies)
        : this(metadataAddress, policies, new HttpDocumentRetriever())
    {
    }

    public PolicyConfigurationManager(string metadataAddress, string[] policies, IDocumentRetriever docRetriever)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metadataAddress))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("metadataAddress");
        }

        if (docRetriever == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("retriever");
        }

        _metadataAddress = metadataAddress;
        _docRetriever = docRetriever;
        _configRetriever = new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever();
        _refreshLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        _syncAfter = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();
        _lastRefresh = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();
        _currentConfiguration = new Dictionary<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration>();

        foreach (string policy in policies)
        {
            _currentConfiguration.Add(policy, null);
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan AutomaticRefreshInterval
    {
        get { return _automaticRefreshInterval; }
        set
        {
            if (value < MinimumAutomaticRefreshInterval)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ErrorMessages.IDX10107, MinimumAutomaticRefreshInterval, value));
            }
            _automaticRefreshInterval = value;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan RefreshInterval
    {
        get { return _refreshInterval; }
        set
        {
            if (value < MinimumRefreshInterval)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ErrorMessages.IDX10106, MinimumRefreshInterval, value));
            }
            _refreshInterval = value;
        }
    }

    // Takes the ohter and copies it to source, preserving the source's multi-valued attributes as a running sum.
    private OpenIdConnectConfiguration MergeConfig(OpenIdConnectConfiguration source, OpenIdConnectConfiguration other)
    {
        ICollection<SecurityToken> existingSigningTokens = source.SigningTokens;
        ICollection<string> existingAlgs = source.IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported;
        ICollection<SecurityKey> existingSigningKeys = source.SigningKeys;

        foreach (SecurityToken token in existingSigningTokens)
        {
            other.SigningTokens.Add(token);
        }

        foreach (string alg in existingAlgs)
        {
            other.IdTokenSigningAlgValuesSupported.Add(alg);
        }

        foreach (SecurityKey key in existingSigningKeys)
        {
            other.SigningKeys.Add(key);
        }

        return other;
    }

    // This non-policy specific method effectively gets the metadata for all policies specified in the constructor,
    // and merges their signing key metadata.  It selects the other metadata from one of the policies at random.
    // This is done so that the middleware can take an incoming id_token and validate it against all signing keys
    // for the app, selecting the appropriate signing key based on the key identifiers.
    public async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration configUnion = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
        Dictionary<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration> clone = new Dictionary<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(_currentConfiguration);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration> entry in clone)
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(cancel, entry.Key);
            configUnion = MergeConfig(configUnion, config);
        }

        return configUnion;
    }

    public async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken cancel, string policyId)
    {
        DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        DateTimeOffset sync;
        if (!_syncAfter.TryGetValue(policyId, out sync))
        {
            sync = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        }

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config;
        if (!_currentConfiguration.TryGetValue(policyId, out config))
        {
            config = null;
        }

        if (config != null && sync > now)
        {
            return config;
        }

        await _refreshLock.WaitAsync(cancel);
        try
        {
            Exception retrieveEx = null;
            if (sync <= now)
            {
                try
                {
                    // We're assuming the metadata address provided in the constructor does not contain qp's
                    config = await OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String.Format(_metadataAddress + "?{0}={1}", policyParameter, policyId), _docRetriever, cancel);
                    _currentConfiguration[policyId] = config;
                    Contract.Assert(_currentConfiguration[policyId] != null);
                    _lastRefresh[policyId] = now;
                    _syncAfter[policyId] = now.UtcDateTime.Add(_automaticRefreshInterval);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    retrieveEx = ex;
                    _syncAfter[policyId] = now.UtcDateTime.Add(_automaticRefreshInterval < _refreshInterval ? _automaticRefreshInterval : _refreshInterval);
                }
            }

            if (config == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ErrorMessages.IDX10803, _metadataAddress ?? "null"), retrieveEx);
            }

            return config;
        }
        finally
        {
            _refreshLock.Release();
        }
    }

    public void RequestRefresh(string policyId)
    {
        DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        DateTimeOffset refresh;
        if (!_lastRefresh.TryGetValue(policyId, out refresh) || now >= _lastRefresh[policyId].UtcDateTime.Add(RefreshInterval))
        {
            _syncAfter[policyId] = now;
        }
    }

    public void RequestRefresh()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenIdConnectConfiguration> entry in _currentConfiguration)
        {
            RequestRefresh(entry.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <!-- Azure AD B2C -->
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="xxx" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxx" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="xxx"/>
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}{2}" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44300/" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44300/" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpPolicyId" value="b2c_1_signup01" />
    <add key="ida:SignInPolicyId" value="b2c_1_signin01" />
    <add key="ida:UserProfilePolicyId" value="b2c_1_profile01" />
    <!-- /Azure AD B2C -->

    <add key="appinsights:instrumentationKey" value="xxx" />

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Enfore HTTPS -->
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.4220" newVersion="1.0.0.4220" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.20622.1351" newVersion="4.0.20622.1351" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.2.33" newVersion="1.0.2.33" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.1.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

For now, I have a "dirty" workaround for the PolicyAuthorize:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (this.Policy.Equals(ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.SIGNIN_POLICY_ID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/SignIn", true);
    }
    else if (this.Policy.Equals(ConfigurationHelper.Authentication.SIGNUP_POLICY_ID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/SignUp", true);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Policy ID {this.Policy} is not supported.");
    }
}
```

But it is not perfect, the debugger still enters my Controller method but then I am redirected to the login page. So for now I am using this even if not perfect.

Comment: are your redirect uri's correct in the config?

Perhaps you can add an AuthorizationCodeRecieved event handler, to see what comes back after the challenge. Like in the sample (ConfigureAuth() ): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet/

Comment: @BobLokerse thanks for the idea! Now that I intercept the AuthorizationCodeReceived event it seems to work as expected. How can I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: Good to hear. I added it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your redirect uri's are correct in the config.

You can add an `AuthorizationCodeRecieved` event handler, to see what comes back after the challenge. 
Like in the sample — i.e  `ConfigureAuth()`:

[B2C quickstart Web-api-dotnet - with AuthorizationCodeRecieved  eventHandler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet/)

Comment: I had a similar issue, but the solution in my case was to put a trailing slash after my redirect URI in the Azure B2C settings (i.e. "https://localhost/TaskService/" not "https://localhost/TaskService").  After doing that, I was able to get the "AuthorizationCodeReceived" handlder to fire.  This was the link/post that led me to the solution:  https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/445 "AuthorizationCodeReceived event won't get called, if RedirectUrl has no final slash!?"

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Then I ported the code to an existing app" is it possible that you missed something? There are several classes in the demo app that have significance to the authentication process. I don't understand them deeply enough to point you to the right one that affects your problem. But files like Startup.Auth.cs, Startup.c, or even Global.asax.cs, have code that is relevant to the full function of the authentication mechanism. Have you checked all of them in your application to ensure they resemble the corresponding code in the demo app that works?

Comment: Yes I ported everything. I updated the initial post to show the other pieces of code.